# Interior Dried Flour or Mold After Storing Bread?

Tags: bread, storage-method, flour, mold, wholewheat

In the photo I've attached to this post, you can see the bread has a white substance at the surface of the interior. This whole wheat bread is cut, then stored in a plastic bread bag (seen in background), and the bag is in an environment away from any heat source. The exposeed interior of bread is placed flat on the surface of the area where I store the bread bag.

This doesn't smell like mold and, visually, it only affects the surface of the exposed interior. My question, is this is mold or dried flour?

I do place flour on top of bread prior to baking. Is it possible flour is dragged down and getting dried up after cutting into the bread? Or could it be something else?

Bread Details:

- Flour Type - Whole Wheat Flour
- Loaf Type - Sandwich
- Yeast - Commercial, active dry yeast
- Dough hydration - 80%
- Dough Type - Lean, only two egg yolks and salt.

Photo Reference:
[image: Photo of Whole Wheat Dough Interior After Storing In Bread Bag, Crumb Placed Down]

Comment: How old is the bread?

Comment: I believe it is almost a week old. I did get an answer at a different source. But I think it's mold. To me, it seemed odd because I've only seen mold growth on the crust of bread and I haven't seen this elsewhere online.

Comment: Likely it will look "more like normal mold" if you give it a few days. But it's mold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say with certainty with one picture, however from the distribution it's very likely mold. The discoloration is evenly spread in the middle, but stops before the crust, if it was flour the patten would be more haphazard and would not be so consistently away from the edges.

I suspect what's happened is by putting the cut side down in a plastic bag you have trapped the moisture, which led to mold growth.

Comment: I think this might of been the case. I intend to buy a Linen Bread Bag. The one I got was a gift, even I was skeptical of using a plastic bread bag.

Comment: I've had limited success with linen bags when storing sandwich loaves, I found the bread dried out very quickly in cloth bags. I let my bread cool completely and then store them in large plastic containers with lockable lids, it keeps the crust pliable and I've found the bread lasts longer.

Comment: How do you find your sandwich bread at such a high hydration level @Eric? I found many recipes are more around 60% which is too dry, I am more around 70 myself.

Comment: I use Whole Wheat Flour and it can soak up much more than all purpose and bread flour. Additionally, higher hydration can provide for a higher rise. 80% is what I set my sights on after going way too high, roughly around 90% - 95% hydration.